# changing color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with code, its probably something stupid that I am not paying attention to.

```
<li><img src="images/red.gif" id="set"
onclick="document.getElementById("set").css("background-color","red")></li>
```

Comment: the element object doesn't have a css method

Comment: Double quotes inside double quotes are cause for error.

Answer (score 0):

The `.css()` function only works for jQuery objects.

```
<li><img src="images/red.gif" id="set" onclick="$('#set').css('background-color', 'red');"></li>
```

You also need to watch your quotes. I wrapped the onclick value in double quotes, and used single quotes inside the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function() {


 $('#set').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
  });


});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <img src="images/red.gif" id="set" >
</li>
```

> Remember that `document.getElementById(...).css is not a function`, so use jquery code instead!
>   Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The .css method can be used on jquery only. If you want to use javascript you have to use the .style method like that:

```html
    <li>
      <img src="images/red.gif" id="set" onclick="document.getElementById('set').style.backgroundcolor = 'red'"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with code?

**Two thinks :**

1. You've a quotes problem (double quotes inside double qoutes) to avoid that you could use single quote `'` :

   ```
   <li.... onclick='document.getElementById("set").css("background-color","red")'></li>
   ________________^____________________________________________________________^
   ```
2. You're trying to access a jQuery method `.css()` on javascript object and that will not work, use jQuery object instead :

   ```
   <li.... onclick='$("#set").css("background-color","red")'></li>
   _________________^^^^^^^^^
   ```

**NOTE :** I suggest to avoid using the inline-event `onclick` and attack click event more in more effecient way using jQuery :

**JS :**

```
$(function() {
    $('#set').on('click', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<li>
    <img id='set' src='images/red.gif'/>
</li>
```

Hope this helps.